# Promesas en javascript

Tags: javascript

El siguiente código produce un error

```js
let promesa = new promise(Function(resolve, reject) {

    setTimeout(Function) {
      resolve('timeout');
    }, 1000);
};
promesa.then(function(data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

La consola informa que hay un paréntesis perdido , pero no alcanzo a darme cuenta cuál es . Además quiero agregar  la pareja try-catch con err.message ¿ dónde ubico ese código?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes algunos errores en este código. Compara con este otro que funciona.
Usas promise y es Promise.
Usas Function en los callback, es function.
En el segndo pones Function), hay te falta un ( queda function()
Por ultimo te falta cerrar el new Promise, tienes }; y es });

```js
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

;

Comment: Ok Gracias por tu comentario

Answer (score 0):

El error es que no pusiste el ultimo paréntesis de la promesa y por eso te marca un error de sintaxis, además de que escribiste mal la instrucción, así debería quedar el código

```js
let promesa = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

    setTimeout(function(){
      resolve('timeout');
    }, 1000);
});
promesa.then(function(data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```